# Error con window.onload con sprites

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tardes,

¿Alguien sabe por qué me salta este error?:

> "coin.render is not a function at window.onload"

El código de mi página web es el siguiente:

```js
    var ImgMoneda = new Image();
    ImgMoneda.src = "coinAnimation.png"

    var canvas;
    var ctx;

    function sprite (opciones){

      var that = {};

      var width = opciones.width;
      var height = opciones.height;
      var image = opciones.image;

      //Función que renderiza el sprite
      var render = function(){

        drawImage(
          that.image,
          0,
          0,
          that.width,
          that.height,
          0,
          0,
          that.width,
          that.height);
      }

      return that;

    }


    var coin = sprite({
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      image: ImgMoneda
    });

    window.onload = function(){
      canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      coin.render();
    }
```

```html
    <canvas id = "miCanvas" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Problemas:

- La función `render` es privada, es decir, que no se puede acceder desde fuera del `scope` de la función `sprite` (*que la contiene*).
- En la llamada a la función `drawImage`, estas intentando acceder a datos que no están guardado en la variable `that`. Ej: `that.image, that.height, etc.`

### Soluciones:

- Registrar en el objeto `that` la función `render`, para que pueda ser accesible mediante `obj.render()`.
- Al llamar a `drawImage` usar las variable del `scope`. (*También podrías guardar estos valores en el objeto `that`, todo depende si quieres poder acceder a estos desde fuera*)

Ejemplo:

```js
var ImgMoneda = new Image();
ImgMoneda.src = "coinAnimation.png"

var canvas;
var ctx;

function sprite (opciones){

  var that = {};

  var width = opciones.width;
  var height = opciones.height;
  var image = opciones.image;

  //Función que renderiza el sprite
  var render = function(){

    // AQUI - Usamos las variables del scope
    drawImage(
      image,
      0,
      0,
      width,
      height,
      0,
      0,
      width,
      height);
  }

  // AQUI - Hacemos público el metodo render
  that.render = render;
  return that;
}


var coin = sprite({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  image: ImgMoneda
});

window.onload = function(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  coin.render();
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "miCanvas" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>
```

Comment: No se debiera instanciar un objeto usando `new sprite(opciones)` ?

Comment: @amenadiel, el resultado es exactamente el mismo si se utiliza el operador `new` o no, ya que cada vez que se llama a la función `sprites`, se crea un nuevo objeto (eg: `var that = {}`).

Comment: Ah, tienes razón. Si se hiciera con new no requeriría retornar `that` pero habría que asignar `this.render` en vez de `that.render`

Answer (score 0):

En vez de ser `var render = function(){}` deberia ser en tu caso `that.render = function(){}`
Y lo mismo para el resto de variables que definis dentro del render, sino no las estarias exponiendo.

```js
var ImgMoneda = new Image();
ImgMoneda.src = "http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png";

var canvas;
var ctx;

function sprite (opciones){

  var that = {};

  that.width = opciones.width;
  that.height = opciones.height;
  that.image = opciones.image;

  //Función que renderiza el sprite
  that.render = function(){

  
    ctx.drawImage(
      that.image,
      0,
      0,
      that.width,
      that.height,
      0,
      0,
      that.width,
      that.height);
  }

  return that;

}


var coin = sprite({
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  image: ImgMoneda
});

window.onload = function(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  coin.render();
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "miCanvas" width = "100" height = "100"></canvas>
```

Comment: hola me puedes explicar perdona que no se bien como hacer para poner el código de esa manera para que los demás lo puedan ejecutar?

Comment: Asi @OmarOmar : [http://imgur.com/zI88VWB](http://imgur.com/zI88VWB)